# Rewriting a "location" into a subdomain in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to turn this URL

```
anothersubdomain.somedomain.dev/admin
```

into

```
admin.somedomain.dev
```

Also taking into consideration any succeeding URL's like

```
anothersubdomain.somedomain.dev/admin/users/etc
```

So it becomes

```
admin.somedomain.dev/users/etc
```

How can it be done using Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your first domain's server config.

```
location ~ /admin(.*) {
    return 301 $scheme://admin.anotherdomain.com$1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would the $1 group also include any URL paramters?

Comment: Yea it should, if it doesn't tell me.